# Error while reading shapefile (The following locker still has a lock)?

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I am working with reading and writing shapefiles. I can read and write a shapefile but while reading it the warning message below is coming in the console, no error is coming.

reading

> 29 Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles
>   logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The following locker still has a lock: read
>   on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shp
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader 29 Aug, 2013
>   12:03:08 PM org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers
>   SEVERE: The following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shx
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile 29 Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The
>   following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.dbf
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader Stopped reading 29
>   Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles
>   logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The following locker still has a lock: read
>   on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shp
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader 29 Aug, 2013
>   12:03:08 PM org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers
>   SEVERE: The following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shx
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile 29 Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The
>   following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.dbf
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader Stopped reading
>   Stopped reading 29 Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The
>   following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shp
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader 29 Aug, 2013
>   12:03:08 PM org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers
>   SEVERE: The following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.shx
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile 29 Aug, 2013 12:03:08 PM
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles logCurrentLockers SEVERE: The
>   following locker still has a lock: read on
>   file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/irumbaishp/irumbaishp/Irumbai_Lands.dbf
>   by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader Stopped reading
>   Stopped

and the code to read the shapefile is:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;

public class GeoOpen 
{

    private static SimpleFeatureIterator simpleFeatureIterator;
    private static String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\irumbaishp\\irumbaishp\\Irumbai_Lands.shp";
    public static boolean openShapeFile() throws Exception
    {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        dataFile.setReadOnly();
        ShapefileDataStore store = new ShapefileDataStore(dataFile.toURL());
        SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource();
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = source.getFeatures();
        simpleFeatureIterator = featureCollection.features();
        return true;
    }
    public static  boolean iterate()
    {
        while(simpleFeatureIterator.hasNext())
        {
            simpleFeatureIterator.next();
        }

    simpleFeatureIterator.close();
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println("reading");
            GeoOpen.openShapeFile();
            GeoOpen.iterate();
            System.out.println("Stopped");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you close the shape file when you finish reading it?

Comment: thanks for your reply Iam using geotools 9.4 version but there is no reference for closing a shape file i tried hard on it i have n't got that.

Comment: Please let me know is there any problem in my code

Comment: you need to close featureCollections - http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html

Comment: hi i have closed simplefeatureiterator after reading the file still iam facing the same problem. this problem happening when iam reading the big shape file please help me

Comment: we'll need more code then

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: I have edited the code when i am reading big shape files iam getting severe warning please help me

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the above code - one thing try http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/code/url.html for creating the URL but that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: Earlier we used to read shape files by using geotools version 2.7 but now we are upgrading geotools 9.4. In getools 2.7 version we were not getting any severe errors but 9.4 we are getting these for the same shapefile what is the reason we are in a confusion whether to use it or not

Comment: I tested with 9.4 - you might need to ask on the mailing list (with a link to all of your code)

Comment: Hi iant,  thi is my sample shape file link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Vh2tWJlQW_NmVrSk5ZWDFYLUU/edit?usp=drive_web&pli=1   please run the code by using this shape

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, wanted to add that you also need to close FeatureSource, FeatureCollection and FeatureIterator if you have them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disposing the datastore after use solves the problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;

public class GeoOpen
{

    private static SimpleFeatureIterator simpleFeatureIterator;
    private static String fileName = "/home/sunish/Temp/shape.shp";
    static FileDataStore store ;

    public  static boolean openShapeFile() throws Exception
    {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        dataFile.setReadOnly();
        store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(dataFile);
       // ShapefileDataStore store = new ShapefileDataStore(dataFile.toURL());

        SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource();
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = source.getFeatures();
        simpleFeatureIterator = featureCollection.features();


        return true;
    }
    public  static boolean iterate()
    {
        try{
        while(simpleFeatureIterator.hasNext())
        {

            SimpleFeature f = simpleFeatureIterator.next();

           System.out.println(""+f.getID());
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            simpleFeatureIterator.close();
            store.dispose();

        }


        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println("reading "+ i);

            GeoOpen.openShapeFile();
            GeoOpen.iterate();

            System.out.println("Stopped");
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```